# How to show multiple checkbox information in another activity when these checkboxes are clicked?

Tags: android, checkbox, sharedpreferences

What we wanted to do is to display the information of the selected checkbox in Desserts Menu into the List Of Final Order (LOFO) activity.

Here is our desserts.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:background="#ffff"
tools:context=".MainMenu" >


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:text="@string/dessertsmenu"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="27dp"
    android:text="@string/meal_ok"
    android:onClick="onClicdesserts_ok" />

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/chkpeach"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/chkpie"
    android:layout_below="@+id/chkpie"
    android:defaultValue="false"
    android:text="@string/peachcrumbbars"
    android:onClick="onClickpeachcrumbbars_ok"  />

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/chksquares"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/chkpeach"
    android:layout_below="@+id/chkpeach"
    android:defaultValue="false"
    android:text="@string/snickerysquares"
    android:onClick="onClicksnicjerysquares_ok"  />

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/chkpie"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_marginLeft="22dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
    android:defaultValue="false"
    android:text="@string/blackberrypiebars"
    android:onClick="onClickblackberrypiebars_ok"  />
```

And here is our DessertsMenu.java:

```
package net.xadtv.yoursmenu;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CheckBox;




public class DessertsMenu extends Activity{
Button button1;
CheckBox chkpie;
CheckBox chkpeach;
CheckBox chksquares;
public static final String MENU_NAME = "MyMenuFile";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.desserts);
button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
chkpie = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.chkpie);
chkpeach = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.chkpeach);
chksquares = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.chksquares);
button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

if(chkpie.isChecked());
SharedPreferences settings1 = getSharedPreferences(MENU_NAME, 0);
SharedPreferences.Editor pie = settings1.edit();
pie.putString("pietext", "black berry pie bars");

pie.commit();

if(chkpeach.isChecked());
SharedPreferences settings2 = getSharedPreferences(MENU_NAME, 0);
SharedPreferences.Editor peach = settings2.edit();
peach.putString("peachtext", "peach crumbbars");

peach.commit();

if(chksquares.isChecked());
SharedPreferences settings3 = getSharedPreferences(MENU_NAME, 0);
SharedPreferences.Editor squares = settings3.edit();
squares.putString("squarestext", "snickery squares");

squares.commit();

Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),LOFO.class);
startActivity(intent);
}
});

}

}
```

This is where we want to put the clicked checkbox information, The List of Final Order Activity.

Here is our lofo.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:background="#277c9b"
tools:context=".MainMenu" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:text="Medium Text"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
    android:text="Medium Text"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:text="Medium Text"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView3"
    android:text="Medium Text"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView5"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView4"
    android:text="Medium Text"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView6"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView5"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView5"
    android:text="Medium Text"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
```

And here is our LOFO.java:

```
package net.xadtv.yoursmenu;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;



public class LOFO extends Activity{
public static final String MENU_NAME = "MyMenuFile";
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

setContentView(R.layout.lofo);

TextView tvpeach = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
TextView tvsquares = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);
TextView tvpie = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView3);

SharedPreferences settings1 = getSharedPreferences(MENU_NAME, 0);
SharedPreferences settings2 = getSharedPreferences(MENU_NAME, 0);
SharedPreferences settings3 = getSharedPreferences(MENU_NAME, 0);

tvpeach.setText(settings1.getString("peach", ""));
tvsquares.setText(settings2.getString("squares", ""));
tvpie.setText(settings3.getString("pie", ""));

}
}
```

The problem now is, once we run it and then check one of the checkbox, an error will occur (Source not Found).

Any help is greatly appreciated. :)

Comment: post the stacktrace/logcat output please. And line numbers if relevant.

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things:

- you have have: if(chkpie.isChecked()); See that semi-colon at the end? that means that the if statement is useless
- you also have two declarations of FILE_MENU. That's sloppy and bad practice. Remove one. Reference the declaration in the second file like so: DessertsMenu.FILE_MENU
- same with the three declarations in LOFO.java of shared preferences

I'm also going to guess that the "source not found" error you are talking about is an exception because you are trying to reference your check box objects in the click listener. This can't be done like this.

Instead try this:

```
button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
SharedPreferences settings1 = getSharedPreferences(MENU_NAME, 0);

switch v.getId()
{
  case R.id.chkpie:
    settings1.edit().putString("pietext", "black berry pie bars").commit(); 
  case R.id.chkpeach:
//.... you see where I'm going with this right? 
}


Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),LOFO.class);
startActivity(intent);
}
});

}
```